# $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}$ projective module?

Tags: homological-algebra

$\mathbb{Z}_n$   is   a $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}$ projective module?  I   try    to   apply   the   definition...

Comment: Does the obvious surjective homomorphism $p:\Bbb{Z}_{n^2}\to\Bbb{Z}_n$ split?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Actually   that's my   problem. How   to   prove   that?

Comment: Well, is there a morphism which splits that surjection? Have you tried to see what happens when $n$ is $2$, for example?

Comment: If $s:\Bbb{Z}_n\to\Bbb{Z}_{n^2}$ is a splitting homomorphism, what can you say about $s(1)$? A) for $s$ to be a homomorphism? B) for $p\circ s$ to be the identity?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   Actually  $s(1) = nk$

Comment: Correct. And why is that a contradiction?

Comment: How can $s$ be defined? Generators must go to generators. But this cannot defined here?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Now $s(n)$   goes to  0,   but  it   must   go  to 1?No?

Comment: @PregatireMatematica what they try to point out, is that the only such a morphism is the trivial one.

Comment: Correct! ${}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The morphism $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z_{n^2}$ sent $1$ to $kn$. This can solve the problem[image]

Comment: Since the epimorphism $Z_{n^2} \rightarrow Z_n$ sent 1 to 1.

Comment: Why?   I   seen   that   before to   ask   here...   But   I   don't   know    why...

Comment: $k$ is what number in that case?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris k is an integer form 0 to n-1

Comment: @PregatireMatematica you need research the morphism,the composition can not be identity.                  What I have said is correct,but you give...........

Answer (score 1):

The group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ can be considered as a module over $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$ by identifying it with the subgroup $n\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$.

The map $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}\to n\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x+n^2\mathbb{Z}\mapsto nx+n^2\mathbb{Z}$ is a surjective homomorphism. If the module is projective, then this homomorphism splits; however, $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique subgroup isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$, which is not a direct summand.